# Identify restrictions in embeddable Youtube videos

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, embed, mobile-website, youtube-data-api

I'm having problems identifying playback restrictions of embedded YouTube videos when using YouTube Data API v3.

Example: YouTube ID k85mRPqvMbE and 3n4dXiagrZc seem to share same restrictions when it comes to embedded playback (in my case on an iPhone). The parameters I have looked at are "embeddable" in Video API and videoSyndicated/videoEmbeddable in Search API.

All the "obvious" parameters give the same results for both videos, but while I can play "3n4dXiagrZc" on my device without any problems, "k85mRPqvMbE" refuses to play due to content owner blocking me from watching it (playback through YouTube app or YouTube web works fine though). Please note that I have check the country restrictions as well and my country is not blocked for any of the two.

Any ideas on how to identify videos via the YouTube Data API v3 that are blocked for the reason stated above?

Answer (score 2):

If you do a JSON query, `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=videoid` you will get the video info. Here look for "embed:allowed", if present the video is embeddable.. Hope this helps! :)